# How to increase the percentage of a number in console app c#?

Tags: c#

I need to increase the percentage of integer "a" for 20 percent if that is lower than 100 and so on with others. I never used percentage so i need to know how this works in c#. This is just a simply code an example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b, c;
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a < 100)
        {
            b = a * 20 %;
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
        else if (a > 200)
        {
            b = a * 30 %;
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
        else if (a == 300)
        {
            b = a * 40 %;
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
        else Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: percentage is just a decimal. Getting "20% of a" is just `a * .20`. Not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: In the end, this is just math. Percentage, in math, is a decimal. `100%` is equal to `1.00`. `50%` is equal to `0.50`. Do your math as decimal, and then to display the result for the end user you can do `a.ToString("0.00%");`. In other words, don't worry about "Percentage" as that is just a way to display for the end user. Worry about the math.

Comment: So what happens when you attempt to run your code? But you have made an incorrect assumption about the percent sign. A search of "c# arithmetic" will be enlightening.

Comment: The code provided has compilation errors. The % sign is an operator and it needs a second operand.

Comment: You need to think about these types of problems in the same way you'd actually solve a straight math problem. If you wanted to write out a percent increase as a formula, you'd explicitly do `x * 1.2` for a 20% increase. If you were to write `x * 20%` you'd probably raise a couple of eyebrows. No need to do anything special in C#. A percent sign is simply for human readability and has no purpose in these types of calculations (as it is the modulus operator, it has meaning in other operations).

Comment: FYI, your last `else if (a == 300)` condition will never execute, since that condition also satisfies the previous condition `else if (a > 200)`. You should reverse the order of those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand, i think you need this :

```
int a, c;
double b;
a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (a < 100)
{
    b = a + a * 0.2;
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
else if (a > 200)
{
    b = a + a * 0.3;
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
else if (a == 300)
{
    b = a + a * 0.4;
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
else 
    Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: Perhaps change the `float` datatype to `decimal`.

Comment: @JPHellemons - Thanks for marking this, in fact it should be `double` !

Comment: What make you think that this calculation `b = a + a * 0.2;` is the percentage.

Comment: @Llazar - This is not percentage. I think the OP wants to increase the value of `a` by 20% which can be done by `b = a + a * 0.2;`

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir if understand what the OP wants then you need to give a bit more of explanation about with you answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better alternative if you used a double instead of % as I will now demonstrate below.

```
int a, c;
double b;
a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if(a < 100)
{
   b = a * 1.2;
   Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Comment: There's a reason you're not allowed yet. You're not going to "trick" the system and post comments as answers... Although with some editing/effort, this can be a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think he needs it to print out as a string and attach the percentage sign to it. In every modern language, '%' is the remainder operator and does not do what you think it does. In that case use the following code:

```C#
int a, c;
double b;
a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (a < 100)
{
    b = a + a * 0.2;
    bFormatted = b.toString() + "%";
    Console.WriteLine(bFormatted);
}
else if (a > 200)
{
    b = a + a * 0.3;
    bFormatted = b.toString() + "%";
    Console.WriteLine(bFormatted);
}
else if (a == 300)
{
    b = a + a * 0.4;
    bFormatted = b.toString() + "%";
    Console.WriteLine(bFormatted);
}
else 
    aFormatted = a.toString() + "%";
    Console.WriteLine(aFormatted);
```